# Python: Removing duplicates from a list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

After reading some data from a file and sorting through it, I get this.

```
[['John', 1], ['Lisa', 2], ['Carly', 2], ['Zacharry', 1], ['Brian', 3], ['John', 5], ['Carly', 2]]
```

How can I removed the duplicates while also adding the values they have so my output would look like this

```
[['John', 6], ['Lisa', 2], ['Carly', 4], ['Zacharry', 1], ['Brian', 3]]
```

I've been able to isolate the duplicates on their own with the total sum of data, however I have no idea how to get my desired output.

Note: Order of the list is important in my case and that my data stays in a list

When I've isolated the duplicates I get this output:

```
[['John', 6], ['Carly', 4]]
```

My Code:

```
def create_bills(filename, capacity):
fob = open(filename)
newlst = list()
for line in fob:
    a = line.split(" $")
    b = [a[0], int(a[1])]
    newlst.append(b)
print(newlst)
newlst2 = list()
for i in range(len(newlst)):
    n = i + 1
    while n < len(newlst):
        if newlst[i][0] == newlst[n][0]:
            newlst2.append([newlst[i][0], (newlst[i][1] + newlst[n][1])])
        n += 1
newlst3 = list()
for i in range(len(newlst)):
    pass
print(newlst2)
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you've isolated the duplicates then you've solved your problem! Show us what you've done and we'll be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give your answer.

```
def out(a):
    x={name:0 for name,value in a}
    for name,value in a:
        x[name]=x[name]+value

    final=[]
    for i in a:
        if (i[0],x[i[0]]) not in final:
            final.append((i[0],x[i[0]])) 
    return final
```

The output is 
[('John', 6), ('Lisa', 2), ('Carly', 4), ('Zacharry', 1), ('Brian', 3)]

Comment: Issue is though that the original order is not present

Comment: Why do you need to preserve the original order? Is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict, more specifically an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep track of the counts:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
lst = [['John', 1], ['Lisa', 2], ['Carly', 2], ['Zacharry', 1], ['Brian', 3], ['John', 5], ['Carly', 2]]
d = OrderedDict()
for k, v in lst:
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = v
    else:
        d[k] += v
print map(list, d.items())
#[['John', 6], ['Lisa', 2], ['Carly', 4], ['Zacharry', 1], ['Brian', 3]]
```

Code readability issue aside, it's important to note that it takes `O(N^2)` complexity if you maintain the counts in a list, like what the original code is doing. The dictionary approach takes `O(N)`.

Comment: This is awesome sir! Thank you very much. One question though, how can I make your answer return what you had printed? for instance, make something equal to "[['John', 6], ['Lisa', 2], ['Carly', 4], ['Zacharry', 1], ['Brian', 3]]"

Comment: You can just change the last line from ``print`` to ``return``, assuming you have put the code into function.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't exactly work, the output becomes this
OrderedDict([('John', 6), ('Lisa', 2), ('Carly', 4), ('Zacharry', 1), ('Brian', 3)])

Comment: That is `d`, which is an `OrderedDict`. The last line transform it into the list representation by `map(list, d.items())`, but leaving the original `d` untouched, of course (if that's what you are thinking...). You can use `result = map(list, d.items())` to "make something equal to" it, or just return it in a function.